# how to put struct "s1" values in another variable

Tags: solidity, remix, solidity-0.5.x

how to put struct "s1" values in another variable.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract MyContract{
    struct student{
        int RollNo;
        string Name;
    }

    student public s1=student({RollNo:1, Name:"Test Bunny"});

    int public disint; string public disname;
    disint=s1.RollNo;
    disname=s1.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign it to a variable directly, you has to do it in a function or constructor 
Corrected Code:
I had moved assignment operation to constructor

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract MyContract{
    struct student{
        int RollNo;
        string Name;
    }

    student public s1=student({RollNo:1, Name:"Test Bunny"});

    int public disint; string public disname;
    constructor() public {
        disint=s1.RollNo;
        disname=s1.Name;    
    }
}
```

Comment: okay, it works thx.

Comment: you can optimize it by assigning it when declaring `int public disint = s1.RollNo; string public disname = s1.Name;`